# Error - jar is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, jar

I get the error mentioned above when I execute jar command in cmd. I tried to solve this problem by going putting the path of the jar.exe file in the "path" variable in My computer> > settings > advanced system settings > environment variables.

This is how i did it -

```
(old path variables here);C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7\bin\jar.exe
```

I saved the changes and tried to run jar in cmd again and got the same error. 
Please tell me my mistake and how to fix it. I need to make this work so that 
I can create jar files via the command line.

Comment: You need to close and reopen cmd once done the steps to take effect :) am using win 7

Comment: and of course restart your cmd else it may not work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The path should only contain directories where the OS will look for executables.  Strip the trailing `"\jar.exe"` to set your path as:

```
(old path variables here);C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7\bin
```

Comment: I removed the jar.exe, closed cmd and ran jar command again and i still get the error.

Comment: There was a space between ; and above path to bin folder. Fixed that and it works.

Comment: add "\" at end.
(old path variables here);C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7\bin\

Answer (score 5):

you have a space : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7\bin\jar.exe

Try with quotes: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7\bin\jar.exe"

Answer (score 3):

Three steps to solve this problem:

1. Check whether in your bin folder `jar.exe` is available or not
2. check for your environmental setting
3. Download jar file [from here](http://originaldll.com/file/jar.exe/29248.html)
   and keep it in bin folder
4. now check for jar it will 100% work
5. keep any jar in your desktop and go to desktop path on cmd prompt and run the command
   `jar xf filename.jar`
6. Now see it is working

Answer (score 0):

I need to do other solution instead:

1. Create shortcut for `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7\bin\java.exe`
2. Open `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`. You can copy the address to file explorer, or you should set it to show hidden files.
3. Copy the previously created shortcut to javapath folder, replacing the existing one. Make sure it's named exactly `java.exe`

Done! There you go.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to set the path of JDK file before creating jar files .
- Another way is set environmental variables in your system .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a valid installation of Java JDK and you already checked if the `java --version` command works properly.
You can solve this problem by following the following steps:

1. Search for "Advanced System Settings"
2. Open "System variables"
3. Click `Path` from the `System Variables` section
4. Press `Edit`
5. In the opened list search for `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and replace it with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\`
6. Click `Ok`
7. Close and reopen the terminal, and it should work now.

You have to add a `\` at the end of the existing path `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` that is added to the main `Path`.